# Disabling and greying out a UITextField in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 `UITextField`'s which I use for logging in. I want to temporarily disable them while the network request is made and then re-enable them once the network request is received.

I was hoping for the `UITextField` to be greyed out as well while they are disabled.

Here is the code for one of the `UITextField`s (they are both virtually identical, if I can disable one, then I can disable the other):

```
self.user = UITextField()
self.user.placeholder = "Username..."
self.user.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.EmailAddress
self.user.frame = CGRectMake(20, 200, 300, 40)
self.view.addSubview(user)
```

I was hoping later in the code I could do something like:

```
self.user.enabled = false
```

But this doesn't seem to have any effect. Am I doing the right thing, and will this grey the `UITextField`s out?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote: *... while the network request is made*

UI changes must be made on the main thread, so you should make your network request on a background thread:

```
self.user.enabled = false

let bg_queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

dispatch_async(bg_queue, {
    // your network request here...

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.user.enabled = true
    })
})
```

Comment: this worked for me and solved a few other issues - many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`self.user.enabled = false` should work. As you are doing a network call its very likely you are not executing this code from main thread (UIKit is not thread safe and should be updated only from main thread). Try the following code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.user.enabled = false
});
```

This way the code will be dispatched to be executed on main thread.

Answer (score 1):

for **swift 3.0**, correct command is:

`myTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()`
so that everything in the View is ignored. Then use `UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()` to let the user continue to use the app.

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else still needs the greying out effect you could just set the alpha property of the textfield e.g userTextfield.alpha = 0.3